# CloudKit Dashboard Time Zone for Date Fields

Tags: cloudkit

What time zone should I be expressing dates in when entered in the CloudKit Dashboard?

I have a record in CloudKit that I'm editing in the CloudKit Dashboard. It has a date field. If I enter the date, it seems to go in as EDT (New York time), which is where I am.

Example: I enter `2019-03-29 19:00:00`, meaning today, 7 PM. I don't specify a time zone.

In my code, I can take a `date` variable from the record and make a string:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short

let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

This outputs, as expected, `Mar 29, 2019 at 7:00 PM`. If I change my device's time zone to London time, it outputs `11 PM`, again, as expected.

Does the CloudKit Dashboard always use one's current time zone when interpreting a date? Or is it always EDT? If I'm traveling, do I enter it relative to my current local time zone?